# Array_sum not adding correctly (returns very small number instead of 0) php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I've a function that adds the values of an sql column and returns the sum. I now realize that using the `SUM` function would have been better. but this function is a very low level function that is used in other functions and many times throughout the project. So, I want to avoid doing that.

For some reason for one specific query the function return a very low number `4.4408920985E-15` rather than `0`, I put all the numbers in *wolfram alpha* and got `0` so I know that it should be this. Also even more baffling is the database only goes up to 10 decimal places so there is no way for php to get something to that decimal place.

Is this a known php problem or is it me?

Here is the function:

```
function column_sum($search, $column) {
    if (database_verify($search)) {
        $rows = database_rows($search);
        $column_array=array($column);
        $column_info = database_array($search, $column_array, $rows);

        for ($i=0; $i < $rows; $i++) { 
            $column_sum[$i] = $column_info[$i][$column]; 
        } // FOR Loop I
        return array_sum($column_sum);
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: float, ieee, precision..

Comment: Thank you. I actually was never sure what a float was didn't know decimals were such a problem in computer science.

Comment: Floats are a stone cold b*tch.

Comment: but how do i fix this? When i use the rounding, or number_format function I still get a crazy number.

Comment: The only ways to fix it are to either not use floats or to not care that it's broken.

Comment: -__- I'm going to bed hopefully everything will magically work tomorrow.